Where do the fission products go?
In Nuclear Fission, I see that the fragments contribute to most of the kinetic energy.

Does this mean the fragments actually come off the rods, travel in water while heating it up and then settle down in the chamber?

If it is not #1 and if the fragments stay intact within the rods, Does the fragments have even a ~1% probability to peel off from the rods and mix with water or settle down in chamber over a period of time?

Is there any image of a real spent nuclear fuel rod?  I tried searching the web, but got only the images of storage chambers.




I am not a nuclear engineering expert, just someone who knows a bit about nuclear fission itself, but I will tell you that you will probably never see a photo of a spent nuclear fuel rod. The radiation is dangerous to cameras and much more dangerous to humans. There's a reason we put them in storage chambers.

@controlgroup I'm extremely sure that humanity had chosen to waste some cameras to take such pictures. For example, we had sent drones into Chernobyl to take some videos. The videos are strongly affected by the radiation, which is fun.

@naturallyInconsistent I mean I'm sure we have photos, but I doubt recent ones. Of course I'm not a nuclear engineer, it's just a thought, but if you count the Chernobyl disaster's aftermath as "spent nuclear fuel" then I'm sure we have photos yeah.

Have you heard of:

radiation length
stopping power
$dE/dx$
minimum ionizing
Bethe-Bloch formula

those all facets of how we've come to understand the interaction of particles with bulk matter.
What you want to do is go to:
https://pdg.lbl.gov/2023/AtomicNuclearProperties/index.html
and look up the properties for elements, e.g. uranium:

For an absolute back-of-the-napkin (not even an envelope) estimate, you look at minimum ionization of 20 MeV/cm.
Basically, charged particles lose energy continuously in matter by interacting with atomic electron. The interaction is described by the Bethe-Bloch formula, and tabulated in tables such as the link above.
The result is usually given in MeV/cm, which is self explanatory.
The energy loss curves generally look like:

The term "minimum ionizing" is used because all the curves show a dip around $\gamma=4$, followed by a logarithmic relativistic rise--idk about the TeV regime, I never worked there.
At non-relativistic speeds, there is a famous $1/\beta^2$ rise (hence: proton beam therapy), it's well described classically in J.D. Jackson's famous "Classical Electrodynamics".
Moreover, the effect goes as $Z^2$, so for a fission product like Kr ($Z=36$), you can pretty much estimate it loses energy at about 20 GeV/cm, or, 200 MeV/ 10 microns:
They're not escaping the fuel rods (ballistically), and any that do are stopped immediately in water. Ofc, they may diffuse out of the rods after they've lost their initial kinetic energy.

The fission products, heavy and highly, even completely ionized particles, have a very short path in the material, typically 3 to 7 micrometers. Thus (and fortunately), they are trapped in the fuel rod and remain in the fuel rod; Those which are emitted near the external surface of the fuel are stopped by the cladding of the fuel rod. In a nuclear reactor, it is therefore first the fuel rod which mainly heats up. Microcracks can occur in the fuel cladding (cladding rupture) with releases of very small quantities of fission products: the problem must be treated immediately, we cannot afford to contaminate the water and the entire circuit primary of the reactor, ultimately making maintenance impossible given the significant contamination. The reactor must be shut down and the fuel assembly with the fault must be replaced. This happened recently on the first load of one of the 2 EPR reactors in Taishan (China).
The control rods trap neutrons (large neutron effective section) in no case fission products.
